# Changing file name of writedlm in Julia with a for loop

Tags: for-loop, save, julia

Is it possible to change the name of a file for each iteration of a loop in Julia, with `writedlm` command? For example, with the following code, at each iteration, the file name is overwritten each time and I want avoid that, preferring different names for each iteration using each index `i` for that:

```
using DelimitedFiles
for i=1:100
    data=rand(50,1000)
    writedlm("candidates.txt", data, " ")
end
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write e.g.:

```
writedlm("candidates_$i.txt", data, " ")
```

This syntax is using interpolation, see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/strings/#string-interpolation-1) for details.

(I assume this is what you needed)

Comment: That's precisely what I want! Always super helpful concerning Julia, @Bogumil Kaminski!